# Extracting formula's argument using another formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-4.0

I need to be able to extract a specific hard-coded argument value from a large number of cells into a new cell.

Let's say a cell has the following formula:

```
=func("value1","value2","value3")
```

I want to extract `value2` into its own cell, all values are of variable length.

I've been able to retrieve the formula as text by adding the following to my name manager:

```
=GET.CELL(6,INDIRECT("RC[-2]",FALSE))
```

But this doesn't really help as the values being variable mean the string length is highly variable on the function values.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find any official information on `GET.CELL`, so I assume it is a user defined function.

This means [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) is already being used. As such, I purpose a new UDF:

```
Function FuncArg(ByVal r As Range, ByVal n As Long)
    Dim a As String
    a = Split(r.Resize(1, 1).Formula, "(", 2)(1)
    a = Split(a, ")")(0)
    a = Split(a, ",")(n - 1)
    FuncArg = Application.Evaluate(a)
End Function
```

So in Excel you could just use formula `=FuncArg(A1, 2)` to return second argument of function in cell `A1`.

Caution, this function must be used under very controlled situations:

- using `Application.Evaluate` makes it quite unsafe;
- only checks first function;
- no parsing for nested functions or string encoded `,` or `)`.

Comment: Superb! Thanks for this, quick, easy and does the job.

Comment: You can even make one liner: `FuncArg = Application.Evaluate(Split(Split(Split(r.Resize(1, 1).Formula, "(", 2)(1), ")")(0), ",")(n - 1))`!!!